# SQL if a Case statement returns a negative number change to zero

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL statement that works fine for the most. I need to subtract 2 from the total sum but on if that would not result in a negative number. If it does result in a negative number then I need a zero.  I can't use a count I have to use Sum.
Basically what I am doing is if the task is finished this week count it -2 but that results in negative numbers and while I can have zero tasks due this week I can't have negative  2 due this week.  The -2 is necessary because of some other fields that I can't eliminate that get counted in the total.

Question: How can I write this to only subtract 2 if it will not result in a negative number

```
,SUM(case when
 T.[TaskFinishDate] <= DATEADD(DAY, 8-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), 
Convert(date,getdate()))  then 1 
    else 0 
    end) - 2 AS Planned
```

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to do (e.g. something like `ISNULL(NULLIF(NULLIF(SUM(...), 0), 1) - 2, 0)` would work) but theoretically you should want to fix up your query so those other fields don't get counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your `case` for a < 0 value and return 0 for less than zero:

```
case when
    SUM(
        case when t.[TaskFinishDate] <= DATEADD(DAY, 8-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), Convert(date,getdate()))then 1 else 0 end) - 2 < 0 
        then 0 
        else 
            SUM(case when t.[TaskFinishDate] <= DATEADD(DAY, 8-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), Convert(date,getdate())) then 1 else 0 end) - 2
end planned
```